# How to use injected constants in html file in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a constant file which looks like this

### demo.constant.js

```
// Add detail constans here
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp').constant('TYPE', {
        DYNAMIC: 'dynamic',
        STATIC: 'static'
    });
}());
```

Now I have a controller file that looks similar to this.

### demo.controller.js

```
(function() {
    var DemoController = function(DEP1,DEP2, .... , TYPE)
    console.log(TYPE.DYNAMIC); // works perfectly
    var self = this;
    self.type = '';
    ...
    ...
    angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('DemoController', DemoController);
})();
```

I am trying to access these constants in the HTML file like this:-

```
<div ng-controller="DemoController as self">
    <span ng-if="(self.type === 'dynamic')"> <!--instead of 'dynamic' I want to use TYPE.DYNAMIC-->
    ...
    ...
    ...
    </span>
</div>
```

Note:- `{{self.type}}` works but `{{TYPE.DYNAMIC}}` doesn't.

Another problem is that I want to use this constant as the value of radio buttons.

somewhat like this:-

```
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="self.inputType" value="dynamic"> <!-- Here I want to use TYPE.DYNAMIC -->
<input type="radio" name="type" ng-model="self.inputType" value="static">  <!-- Same as above -->
```

I have searched everywhere but nothing seems to work. Please Help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to assign the constant to a controller property:

```
function DemoController(DEP1,DEP2, /*.... ,*/ TYPE) {
    console.log(TYPE.DYNAMIC); // works perfectly

    this.TYPE = TYPE;
}
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('DemoController', DemoController)
```

Then use it in the template:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoController as $ctrl">
    <span ng-if="$ctrl.type === $ctrl.TYPE.DYNAMIC">
    ...
    </span>
</div>
```

**Note:** The `ng-if` directive uses creates a child scope. Consider instead using the `ng-show` directive which uses CSS and less resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $rootScope and initilize it in run phase:

```
angular.module('app')
  .run(function ($rootScope, TYPE) {
      $rootScope.TYPE = TYPE
   });
```

then you can use it directly in your HTML